# Density of Brownian motion conditional on staying above 0

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, conditional-probability, brownian-motion

Let $X_t=\mu t + \sigma W_t$ where $B_t$ is the standard Brownian motion. What is the density for $X_{t^\prime}$ with $t^\prime \in [0,q]$ conditional on $X_t\geq 0 \ \forall t \in [0,q]$.

I tried starting the simple case with $\mu=0$ and $\sigma=1$. What I know is the distribution when $t^\prime=q$

$$f(x)=\frac{2(x)}{\sqrt{2 \pi q^3}} \exp \left(-\frac{x^{2}}{2 q}\right)$$

which follows from the joint distribution of the running minimum and value of of BM.

It would be great to get some tips about how to condition on the event of staying above 0 for the interval [0,q], when writing the density of of BM at time $t<q$.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Thank you, just updated it to capture more of my insight and problem!

Comment: I think you probably want something so that $X_0 \ne 0$, otherwise you're conditioning on an event with probability $0$.